# Sending an HTTP PUT request with a parameter in C#

Tags: c#

I have a tika server open on my PC, and I need to send it a request with a string parameter which is a path for a file I want tika to process. The code I have so far is:

```
private void getFromServer(string fileName)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9998/rmeta");
    httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";
    httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string postData = @"C:\Users\######\Downloads\elasticsearch\elasticsearch-1.7.1.zip";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        string json = postData;

        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        //Now you have your response.
        //or false depending on information in the response
        console.write(responseText);
    }
}
```

The thing is, the server gets the request, but it returns the string I sent it instead of the contents of the file in question, and I know it can work because I sent it the same request using a cURL command and it worked. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

PS the hashtags are instead of my username

Comment: What is the response's status code? The server probably returned an error status code. Besides, shouldn't you be sending *the file contents* to Tika? Your code simply sends the file path, not the file contents

Comment: Acutaly, The server returns the string I sent it, no errors. But to be honest, I don't know how to send the file itself to the server.

Comment: Turns out  needed to upload the file itself rather than the string. Now it works. Thanks